# Unit test for ansible dynamic inventory plugin

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have been trying to find an example unit test for dynamic inventory plugin but could not find any. Is it because it's not possible to mock internal objects like inventory, loader, path which are required parameter to parse method in Inventory plugin class.
How to mock these objects and pass it to   parse method?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to write unittest for my inventory plugin.

```
import pytest
from unittest import mock
from unittest.mock import patch
from ansible.inventory.data import InventoryData
from plugins.inventory.myinvnetoryplugin import InventoryModule
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader


config_data = {
        'plugin': 'my_inventory'
}


@patch('my_plugin.InventoryModule._read_config_data')
@patch('my_plugin.InventoryModule.get_cache_key') # if you have caching enabled
def test_parse(mock_key, mock_config):
    inventory = InventoryModule()
    inventory.load_cache_plugin = mock.MagicMock()
    inventory.inventory = InventoryData()
    loader = DataLoader()
    mock_config.return_value = config_data
    mock_key.return_value = 'test'

    # pass  inventory, loader, path and cache parameter to parse method
    inventory.parse(inventory.inventory, loader, mock_conf, False)
    
    groups = inventory.inventory.get_groups_dict()
    # Write your asserts here
    assert 'test' in groups
    assert 'host1' in inventory.inventory.hosts
```